# Where is the man or manpage for a flatpak application?

Tags: command-line, manpage, flatpak, ebooks, calibre

How would I read the `man` page for `calibre` when it's installed from `flatpak` as below?

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ flatpak info com.calibre_ebook.calibre

calibre - The one stop solution to all your e-book needs

          ID: com.calibre_ebook.calibre
         Ref: app/com.calibre_ebook.calibre/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 5.23.0
     License: GPL-3.0
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: system
   Installed: 360.9 MB
     Runtime: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08
         Sdk: org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/20.08

      Commit: 13464e660f35716a725261af4b45d3abc199a3ce52ebdd9ee887c7ae623b5873
      Parent: 4f7f3b603f31cc781caf8260f887118a1bb466748891c9e122826728e25d3eed
     Subject: Update calibre-5.22.1-x86_64.txz to 5.23.0 (9184a3f3)
        Date: 2021-07-11 19:56:21 +0000
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ flatpak --version
Flatpak 1.8.2
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ man calibre
No manual entry for calibre
nicholas@gondor:~$
```

The search results I see are for how to use `flatpak` itself, which is only indirectly the question.  No doubt the `man` pages are on the system itself.

Comment: To my knowledge, Flatpaks aren't required to install manpages.  It's quite possible they won't install manpages for the various commands.

Comment: Nicholas... I've clarified my answer a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calibre` doesn't have man pages, if you've installed calibre v5.23.0 from their web page at https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux. This is the recommended place to get the latest version of calibre.

**Note**: The flatpak version v5.23.0 from https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.calibre_ebook.calibre doesn't appear to have man pages either.

**Note**: At the https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux web page, they indicate *"Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described below..."*.

If however, you've installed the older version of calibre v5.11.0 from the Ubuntu repos, or the `Software` app, it may in fact have man pages. Not recommended.

Start `calibre`. Click the HELP icon, or go to https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/ to view the calibre User Manual.

Comment: Better wording is "`calibre` doesn't have a man page *when installed using Flatpak*." See https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/all/calibre/filelist for actual man pages inside deb-package.

Comment: @N0rbert I don't have calibre installed from the Ubuntu repos as it's an older version. That package may come with man pages. I have calibre directly from their web site at https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux where they caution *"Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described below."* and it has no manpages, just as the OP found out. I'll clarify my answer.